# How to reuse the same Groups,Term Sets and Terms for another web applications site collection

Tags: 2013, managed-navigation, managed-metadata-service

Hi I have a SharePoint 2013 Dev farm and one Manged Metadata Service application , i want to create another managed metadata service application in same farm with the backup of existing managed metadata service application.
here i want to

1. How to take backup of Manged Metadata Service application using powerhsell
   2.Restore in Same farm with another Name.
   Purpose is i want to use the same Groups,TermSets and Terms for another web applications site collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to clone Managed Metadata Service (MMS) in the same SP 2013 Farm

1. Find out the database name and Application Pool of the existing MMS in the Farm using PS script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$md=Get-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity "Managed Metadata Service"
$md.Database.DisplayName
$md.ApplicationPool
```

2. Take a full backup of the MMS database and restore using SQL Server Management Studio
   While restoring, make sure to type in a different database name at Destination=>Database => Dropdown list and also, under Files, change the name of the *.mdf and *_log.ldf file to create new files

Here is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XVpOrXLuWg) video to accomplish this.

3. Create a NEW MMS with the PS script shown below. Make sure MMS name is different from the existing one and Database is pointing to the newly restored database.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$mms = New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name "Managed Metadata Service New" -ApplicationPool "SharePoint Web Services Default" -DatabaseName "ManagedMetadataServiceNew"

New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Name 'Managed Metadata Services New Proxy' -ServiceApplication $mms -DefaultProxyGroup
```

4. Verify the newly created MMS using PS or in CA

```
$md=Get-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity "Managed Metadata Service New"
$md.Database.DisplayName
$md.ApplicationPool
```